# Verilog: if statement unexpected behavior

Tags: if-statement, mips, verilog

I am implementing the MIPS data path (behavioral) in Verilog and the when I simulate my code, the behavior is unexpected.
Here the case of BEQ and BNE (branch if equal/not equal) instructions is shown. ALU_Out determines whether the two registers are equal or not. Non of these really matter cause my problem is basically how verily skips my condition. So, I from the signals in waveform, ALU_out **is** zero, yet whatever happens inside the **if (ALU_Out == 32'd1)** is executed once. such that My PC becomes PC+6. now if my ALU_Out actually equals 1, the PC becomes PC+6+6 (It's 1 ==> becomes 13) I have also integrated some kinna flags inside this if statement and made sure it executes once.
Even when I added **else** to this if, my flags clearly indicated that the **if had been executed once before else**.
The very same thing occurs in the case of BNE and desired condition is checked after the if statement is executed once.
Would you tell me what is wrong with this code.
Many thanks in advance.

```
            if (ALU_op == 6'd30)        //BEQ
            begin
                ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) == (ALU_in2));
                if (ALU_out == 32'd1)
                    begin
                        PC = PC + Imm_32;
                    end
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd31)        //BNE
            begin
                ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) == (ALU_in2));
                if (ALU_out == 0)
                    begin
                        PC = PC + Imm_32;
                    end
            end
```

[a screen shot of my waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtRQB.png)

**UPDATE:** still haven't done anything about the non-blocking assignment, But i did modify the way I update PC by adding a next_PC to my code.the If statement problem is gone. Still, the problem is when a jump or branch occurs, the next PC is calculated properly but the instruction at the branch target won't be fetched the same clock! 
[please look at this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0q0o.png)

and this is supposed to be a single-cycle MIPS processor so that an instruction should be fetched and executed at one cycle. that's why the delay caused by non-blocking assignment is not desired!

```
always @(*)
    begin
        IR <= Instruction;
    end
always @(posedge clk)
    begin

        PC = next_PC;

        OverFlow = 0;

    end

// Decode + Operand Fetch //    
always @ (IR)
    begin
        Op_code = IR[31:26];
        if (Op_code == 6'd0)        //R-type Instructions
            begin
                Func = IR[5:0];


                if (Func == 6'b100000)  //ADD
                    begin
                        ALU_op = 6'd1;          //as numbered in LAB manual
                        read_addr1 = IR [25:21];    //Rs
                        read_addr2 = IR [20:16];    //Rt

                    end     //end of ADD


                if (Func == 6'b100001)  //ADDU
                    begin
                        ALU_op = 6'd2;          //as numbered in LAB manual
                        read_addr1 = IR [25:21];    //Rs
                        read_addr2 = IR [20:16];    //Rt
                    end     //end of ADDU


                /* some code here skipped to make the code shorter*/

            if (Op_code == 6'b000100)   //BEQ (Branch if Equal)
                begin
                    ALU_op = 6'd30;         //as numbered in LAB manual
                    read_addr1 = IR [25:21];    //Rs
                    read_addr2 = IR [20:16];    //Rt
                    Imm_32 = {{16{IR[15]}},IR [15:0]};  //Offset 2nd operand: imm-32 (Sign Extended Imm_16) 
                    //BT =  PC + Imm_32;
                end


            if (Op_code == 6'b000101)   //BNE (Branch if NOT Equal)
                begin
                    ALU_op = 6'd31;         //as numbered in LAB manual
                    read_addr1 = IR [25:21];    //Rs
                    read_addr2 = IR [20:16];    //Rt 
                    Imm_32 = {{16{IR[15]}},IR [15:0]};  //Offset 2nd operand: imm-32 (Sign Extended Imm_16)  
                end


            if (Op_code == 6'b000001)   
                begin
                    if ( IR [20:16] == 5'b00001)    //BGEZ (Branch on Greater than or Equal to Zero)
                        begin
                            ALU_op = 6'd33;         //as numbered in LAB manual
                            read_addr1 = IR [25:21];    //Rs
                            Imm_32 = {{16{IR[15]}},IR [15:0]};  //Offset 2nd operand: imm-32 (Sign Extended Imm_16)  
                        end


                    if (IR [20:16] == 5'b10000)     //BLTZAL (Branch on less than Zero And Link)
                        begin
                            ALU_op = 6'd34;         //as numbered in LAB manual
                            read_addr1 = IR [25:21];    //Rs
                            Imm_32 = {{16{IR[15]}},IR [15:0]};  //Offset 2nd operand: imm-32 (Sign Extended Imm_16)  
                        end
                end


            if (Op_code == 6'b000010)   //J (Jump)
                begin
                    ALU_op = 6'd35;         //as numbered in LAB manual
                    Imm_32 = {PC [31:26],IR [25:0]};    //Jump Address  
                end


            if (Op_code == 6'b000011)   //JAL (Jump And Link)
                begin
                    ALU_op = 6'd36;         //as numbered in LAB manual
                    Imm_32 = {PC [31:26],IR [25:0]};    //Jump Address  
                end                     


    end // end of DECODE

// Execution & Write Back//

always @ (ALU_op, ALU_in1, ALU_in2)
    begin
        next_PC = PC+1;
        wr_En = 0;  
        DM_wrEn_0 = 0;
        DM_wrEn_1 = 0;
        DM_wrEn_2 = 0;
        DM_wrEn_3 = 0;

        if (ALU_op == 6'd1)     //ADD
            begin
                ALU_out = ALU_in1 + ALU_in2;
                write_addr = IR [15:11];    //Rd
                if( ( (ALU_in1[31]) && (ALU_in2[31]) && (!ALU_out[31]) )||( (!ALU_in1[31]) && (!ALU_in2[31]) && (ALU_out[31]) ) )
                    OverFlow = 1'b1;
                wr_En = 1;
                write_data = ALU_out;                       
            end

        if (ALU_op == 6'd2)     //ADDU
            begin
                ALU_out = ALU_in1 + ALU_in2;
                write_addr = IR [15:11];    //Rd
                wr_En = 1;
                write_data = ALU_out;                   
            end


        /* some code here skipped to make it shorter*/



        if (ALU_op == 6'd30)        //BEQ
            begin
                ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) == (ALU_in2));
                if (ALU_out == 32'd1)
                    begin
                        //PC = PC + Imm_32;
                        next_PC = PC + Imm_32;
                        BT = 32'd56;
                        //PC = BT;
                    end
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd31)        //BNE
            begin
                ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) == (ALU_in2));
                if (ALU_out == 0)
                    begin
                        //PC = PC + Imm_32;
                        next_PC = PC + Imm_32;
                        BT = 32'd90;
                    end
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd33)        //BGZE
            begin
                ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) >= 0);
                if (ALU_out)
                    begin
                        //PC = PC + Imm_32;
                        next_PC = PC + Imm_32;
                    end
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd34)        //BLTZAL
            begin
                ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) < 0);
                if (ALU_out)
                    begin
                        write_addr = 5'd31; //$ra ($31)
                        write_data = PC;
                        wr_En = 1;
                        //PC = PC + Imm_32;
                        next_PC = PC + Imm_32;
                    end
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd32)        //JR
            begin
                //PC = ALU_in1;
                next_PC = ALU_in1;
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd35)        //J
            begin
                //PC = Imm_32;
                next_PC = Imm_32;
            end


        if (ALU_op == 6'd36)        //JAL
            begin
                write_addr = 5'd31; //$ra
                wr_En = 1;
                write_data = PC;
                //PC = Imm_32;
                next_PC = Imm_32;
            end

    end  //end of EXE and WB always block
```

Comment: Is this in a combinatorial process (`always @*`) or Sequential (`always @(posedge clk)`) ? It looks like you will be mixing assignment styles blocking (`=`) with non-blocking (`<=`) when this is written correctly `PC = PC + Imm_32;` should really be `PC <= PC + Imm_32;`

Comment: Have you tried `ALU_out = ((ALU_in1) == (ALU_in2)) ? 1 : 0`. In case, any previous `1` in ALU_OUT is remaining..? An **alternative** maybe `if( ((ALU_in1) == (ALU_in2)) ) begin ALU_out<=1;PC<=PC+...; end`. Try using nonblocking assignments and some debug messages.

Comment: Morgan is probably correct that you are mixing combinational and sequential logic in a single block that results in undesired behavior. You should probably separate the actual assign of `PC` to its own sequential block and have a `nextPC` determined combinationally.

Comment: @sharvil111 thanks for ur response. I actually tried that as well! still my PC becomes 7 (1+6)

Comment: @Morgan Thanks for your reply. Actually I have 2 always blocks: always @(posedge clk) in which the instruction is fetched and its corresponding ALU_Op is determined (this is the input of the decode part) the next always is sensitive to this ALU_Op (as well as operands in case two consecutive instructions are the same). Now, this if is happening inside this always

Comment: and the thing with blocking vs. non-blocking: I personally believe they  should be non-blocking assignments. though when I first coded that way, my instructions were fetched one cycle later! it was not synched! my instructor said it was ok to have all my assignments as blocking. (I still don't have a good feeling about it! yet, when i changed it this way it worked)

Comment: @Unn hi there! I actually have another version in which I have a next_PC thing and update my PC in a separate always block. Still the problem with executing this if statement was there!!!

Comment: as your gut feeling goes they should be non-blocking (`<=`) inside the edge sensitive process. A flip-flop requires this to simulate correctly. This will indeed cause a 1 clock cycle delay, this is how a flip-flop works. this could be thought of the decoding [pipeline delay of the processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline#The_classic_five_stage_RISC_pipeline).

Comment: @LadyMillionM without seeing that code, I cannot say why it was that you were experiencing the extra addition. You should have code that looks like: `always @(posedge clk) begin PC <= nextPC; end` for assigning the program counter and the combinational block `always @(*) begin ... nextPC = PC + Imm_32; ... end` for determining the next one. Note as Morgan said, this will give you a 1 cycle gap in your pipeline as determining `nextPC` happens in the execute phase of the standard MIPS pipeline, while determining something like `ALU_Op` happens in decode.

Comment: And this gap led to the famous branch delay slots in MIPS (google "branch delay slot" if you dont know the concept)

Comment: @Unn well I did s you said, and updated my PC via a next_PC thing...so i explained what happened in the UPDATE in my post

Comment: @Morgan as explained in my update, this is supposed to be a single-cycle MIPS, so each instruction should be fetched and executed in a single clock and cannot bear the clock miss...I mean the desired scenario here is: on a posedge of clock, the PC indicates an instruction, let's say inst 1, this the very inst should be executed in this cycle...when I used <= instead of =, the PC  indicated an inst which would be fetched and executed during the next cycle!

Comment: Fetching from memory takes 1 cycle, so pretty sure you can not branch, jump to a different instruction and have the new memory reads ready in time. Branching will cost you a cycle.

Comment: @Morgan I see your point. so, I mean, imagine the current inst (PC=1)  is BEQ and it decides that the next PC is 7 (instead of 2 for example). so with the next rising edge of the clock, the PC is 7 and the 7th instruction should be in IR...isn't this possible? did u look at the 2nd photo I linked above? everything works perfectly excepts when a Jump pr Branch occurs! :(

Comment: @Morgan please see this pic: https://imgur.com/delete/M2CnqZK2pxdcESD   instruction fetch takes about 100 ps while my current clock period is 20 ns so it does take less than a cycle. And my PC is connected to the inst memory address line. The weird thing is that the inst is always fetched properly, yet when the PC is changed to branch target (and it properly changes with the rising edge of clock) the instruction is not fetched from that target address! the instruction following the branch/jump instruction is fetched, and after that, the instructions are fetched properly from Target address+1!

Comment: the issue regarding when PC count changes with branch but the decoded instruction does not update correctly,  sounds like something the PC+1 is decoded as the instruction and when you branch you need to void the next instruction. or you need to sample the updated PC at time after it has been calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we know you want it to be single cycle, that clarifies alot.

First, youll need to decide were youre registers are for talking to the memory, are you putting the address to access the instruction memory in a register or the resulting instructions because right now with your `always @(*) IR <= Instruction; end` and `always @(posedge clk) begin PC = nextPC end`, youre doing a weird combination of both. You need to do either:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  IR <= Instruction;
  PC <= nextPC;
end
```

And address the instruction memory with `nextPC` or:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  PC <= nextPC;
end

assign IR = Instruction;
```

And address the instruction memory with `PC`. Note that Morgan's comment the reading from memory should take a cycle is generally correct, however, we will assume you have some kind of combinationally-read memory that does not need a latched address and output/input. In real systems, you really should be prepared to have registers on address and input/output bus to memory though.

A few other stylistic notes:

- Its best not to write your own sensitivity lists, use `always @(*)`, not `always @(IR)` for combinational logic (using `always @(posedge clk)` for sequential logic.
- Use blocking assign (`=`) in `always @(*)` (combinational) blocks and NBA (`<=`) in `always @(posedge clk)` (sequential) blocks.
- Use case statements rather than a long list of `if .. if .. if ..` for decoding opcodes. Its much easier to read
- I suggest replacing the opcodes with parameters or macros so the code reads easier (like instead of `if (op == 6'b001001)`, you get `parameter ALU_ADD = 6'b001001; ... if (op == ALU_ADD)`, its much clearer; even better in a case stamement `case (op) ALU_ADD: ... ALU_SUB: ... ALU_OR: ... endcase`)

Comment: Thank you so very much! nice tips by the way :) well I did change the IR things (I made it a wire an used the assign statement) Still I get the very same waveform! :( in the case of a branch or jump, the PC changes properly but the following instruction is fetched instead of where the PC points to (branch target)!

Comment: the same story as the 2nd waveform screen shot I linked)

Comment: oh and by the way, i created the same file using <= everywhere I used = and what happens is that the PC and next_PC are unknown (X) in the waveform!

Comment: @LadyMillionM What does the instruction memory look like? If it takes a cycle to access, this model has to change.

Comment: IP core memory block- single port RAM, width 32 bits, length 1024. I am pretty sure it takes less than a cycle here. when the if statement executed (wrongly) the delay of fetching the inst from inst memory was visible in my waveform, which was around 100 ps (my clock period is 20 ns now)

Comment: you can see it for yourself in this pic (inst 1 ins beq, and the if was executed upon beq and changed the PC to 7) there is a gap between 1 and 7 as you see, and when you zoom in you'll see that's how long it takes for the IR to change which is the fetch delay : http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtRQB.png

Comment: here is another photo of my current signals (including next PC) and I zoomed in so that you can see the instruction fetch delay. BTW my inst memory address line is connected to PC:  https://imgur.com/delete/M2CnqZK2pxdcESD

Comment: The weird thing is that the inst is always fetched properly, yet when the PC is changed to branch target (and it properly changes with the rising edge of clock) the instruction is not fetched from that target address! the instruction following the branch/jump instruction is fetched, and after that, the instructions are fetched properly from Target address+1!

Comment: Can you provide a link to an EDA playground (http://www.edaplayground.com/) with your current code? Im not sure you have provided enough code for me to pin down the problem completely.

Comment: sure : http://www.edaplayground.com/x/LnY    and I hope you don't mind all those comments in my code! I know it looks nasty now, it's just because I've been debugging and changing a whole lotta stuff! :) sorry

Comment: BTW I just added the inst memory address signal to my waveform and as you see, the address is given correctly (1) but the inst is fetched soooo wrongly!!!!! (inst 6!) : https://imgur.com/delete/wbE2ER9V96YzTJG

Comment: I cannot simulate the EDA program code without the module declarations. However, you still use explicit sensitivity lists for your combinational logic which do NOT include add dependent variables, for example the ALU logic depends on `PC` but `PC` does not appear in the sensitivity list. Also, as you mentioned your memory modules are IP cores, they probably have some registers in them, meaning you must address using `nextPC`. I can see in your latest waveform what I think is correct behavior under this assumption, but I cannot know without simulating the system myself.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your time and help. I can email you my entire file..Or I can upload it to dropbox and give u the link if it's more convenient for you :)

Comment: The program stored in my instruction memory is finding GCD of two numbers stored in $s0 and $s1...This program works properly because I added a noop after each jump/branch...still I am dying to know what is wrong with it! I'd be grateful if you could help me with it

Comment: After looking at the docs for the memory IP core you are using, it takes 1 cycle for the data at the given address to be propagated to the output (ie, address in is set during on cycle, data out will be available on the next cycle), thus you need your entire MIPS core to be combinational if you want single cycle performance. Thus, address the instruction ROM with `nextPC`, not `PC` as you code does now. Note however that this combinational logic will be quite large, thus limiting your maximum clock frequency significantly.

Comment: Thanks..I have tried using next_pc as the memory input for address but it did not execute properly and just did some crazy stuff! i also winder why it functions correctly for any instruction but branch and jump

Comment: I mean as for other instructions, the instruction is fetched in the same clock its address is given to memory